# Records are not getting updated with ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

I have some JDBC stuff defined over [here](https://ideone.com/sxOnZo).

I am basically, grabbing records from one table(`test.selectiontable`) located at `11.11.1.111` and inserting into `22.22.2.222`(`test.insertiontable`). It's a thread based process, so the thread will keep on looking & transferring 
the records until all records are transferred.

and

Since I don't want to insert duplicate records into another table, I have a field in `test.selectiontable`, called `DTSStatusType_ti` which has initial value of `1` in the table. Hence,I am updating it after transferring the records 
to `test.insertiontable` as follows:

```
Line # 112  SelectQueueRS.updateInt( "DTSStatusType_ti", 3 );
Line # 113  SelectQueueRS.updateString( "Queued_DialerIP_vch", 22.22.2.222 );
```

The initial value of `Queued_DialerIP_vch` in `test.selectiontable` is `11.11.1.111`.

Although the records are getting updated using above two lines of code in my code but I don't think it's an efficient way to update. Could anyone please suggest some efficient way to update the records and 100% make sure that these records are not duplicated ever. Please feel free to suggest any changes in my code. Thanks

Comment: Your title and your question itself are in contradiction (specifically "the records are getting updated")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating the ResultSet of the original query, you can:

1. Start a transaction with `connMain.setAutoCommit(false)`
2. If others can modify the data, you should use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` which locks the selected rows
3. Collect the primary key ids from the query result
4. Do the insert to the remote datasource
5. Update the original table with one update query, by the collected ids (`WHERE id IN (...)`)
6. Commit the transaction with `connMain.commit()`

3 and 4 can be done in the same cycle.
By the way you can also start a transaction on the remote datasource and do a batch insert.
You should also be aware of doing transactions in try-catch blocks and closing your resources. This may help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: 1. Started on Line # 8
2: No one will be modifying the data as it is one time transfer process from one database to another so I think I should skip this step.
3.Collected in `PrimaryIdList` on line #62
4.Did Insertremote to test.insertiontable
5. Are you telling me to replace `SelectQueueRS.updateInt( "DTSStatusType_ti", 3 );` with something the update query. What fields I should update specifically correcponding to the Id's?
6.Added commit on line #170 

Updated Link :https://ideone.com/PWRGvu

Comment: I've made changes in your original code with `// MOD:` comments. I've also added some notes (`// NOTE:`). [Here it is](https://ideone.com/XkCWDh)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.1) Do you think that the AutoCommit should be set to true after commit?2) My second concern is that if I have more than one connRemote,  like `22.22.2.222, 33..33.3.333`, then I will be 
inserting the same `5`records from `test.selectiontable` to the `test.Insertiontable` located in each of the location, viz, `22.22.2.222, 33..33.3.333`

Comment: Could you please look my new thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902897/need-to-stop-inserting-same-records-to-different-databases regarding the problem I am facing. Thanks.